# Can't run the app on emulator "Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'"

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have a problem that recently gets annoying. I just started with Android Studio, I am following the course from lynda.com. I set up the AVD, it works perfectly. Then I create the default "Hello World" app - and it already can't be run on the device!

It throws me the following error log:

```
 AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Exception in thread \"main\" ","sources":[{}]}
```

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.604 secs

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Exception in thread \"main\" ","sources":[{}]}

I tried to refer to solutions seen in other questions, but none of them fits me. Any ideas? I did not change anything in the blank activity created.

Also here is my Top-level Gradle code:

```
    <pre><code>

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.hsport.catalog"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            //multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    }

</pre></code>

And the App-level:

<pre><code>

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files


}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Change in build.gradle

```
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion "23.3.0"
```

Comment: @JitendraSingh That may make the problem go away, but it doesn't fix (or explain) the problem with using 24.0.0 rc3, which is a perfectly valid version of the build tools. I have the same error when using Android Studio, but everything builds fine when I use the command line.

Comment: @AndrewKelly 24.0.0 rc3, supported only in Android Studio 2.1 andJava 8 language features, you need to use Android Studio 2.1 to build your app.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.1, I'll try switching to Java 8 to see if that makes a difference (I'm currently using Java 7).